# Fixing "super + number" shortcut's inconsistent UX when 2 windows open

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

The Super + Number shortcut works fine for me as long as I only have open 1 window of each application.

Once you have 2 windows of that same application open, then hitting for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, no longer opens the second application.  Instead it opens an icon in the bottom left that you then have to click on (or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

I would expect it to just open whatever window I was last using (as in Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows).  Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: On GNOME Shell 3.36.7, SUPER + [number] when there's tow or more windows from the same application cycles between each window.

Comment: That's unconventional and one of the many reasons I'm using Ubuntu+Unity still, is there any way to disable that?